# iOS: Count arrays inside the NSDictionary under one key

Tags: ios, arrays, nsdictionary

```
NSDictionary
[
   key0 : {Array1, Array2, Array3},
   key1 : {Array1, Array2},
   key2 : {Array1, Array2, Array3, Array4}
]
```

My answer should be like

key0 contains 3 array.

key1 contains 2 array.

key2 contains 4 array

I need count of an array under a particular key.

Comment: Read the NSDictionary class reference to access the array for a key https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/ and then read https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/index.html to get the count

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following code

```
 NSMutableArray *countArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
 //or
 NSMutableDictionary *countDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

 for( NSString *aKey in [yourDictionary allKeys] ) {
     NSInteger count = [[yourDictionary objectForKey:aKey] count];

     [countArray addObject : count];
     //or
     [countDictionary setObject : count forKey : aKey];
 }
```

`countArray` is just a demo to keep array of item count anyway you can use `NSMutableDictionary` to save with key for more clear answer